# Add content of the file as body in mail unix

Tags: email, unix

I want to add contents of file in body part of the mail in unix,
Also before the file I want to add some text.

Now I'm using this

```
echo "Text is here" >> Filename
mailx -s "subject" zzz@z.com  < Filename.
```

It edited the file.
So,I want my mail body to be like this.

> Text is here
>
> Content of file.

I want to do this without editing the file.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I think it is programming only. I am using shell language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a temporary file and invert the order:

```
echo "Some text" > /tmp/mailbody
cat Filename >> /tmp/mailbody
mailx -s "Subject" zzz@z.com < /tmp/mailbody
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use *command substitution* with *here strings* (available in bash):

```
mailx -s "subject" zzz@z.com  <<< "$( echo Before; cat Filename; echo After )"
```

Comment: Can I use in korne?

Comment: Yes. Ksh supports it.

Comment: I tried on ksh93 and it works. `echo $KSH_VERSION` prints `Version AJM 93t+ 2010-06-21`. Perhaps, you are using some other shell.

Comment: It gives error fr <<<. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: I stick with using another temp file for this.Thanks for your help